# Как сгенерировать карту сайта если ссылок очень много (несколько миллионов)

Tags: xml, sitemap

Как сгенерировать карту сайта если ссылок миллионы. Php скрипты зависают при запуске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите создать карту сайта и у вас очень много ссылок на данном ресурсе, вам необходимо создать несколько файлов sitemap.xml

> Каждый файл sitemap имеет лимит по весу 50MB (без сжатия) и, в каждом файле должно быть максимум 50,000 ссылок.

Получается что вы не можете создать один файл и залить все миллионы ссылок в этот файл, даже если ваш сервер не будет зависать. Вам необходимо создавать `xml` файлы исходя из лимитов, т.е вы в `php` запросе устанавливаете лимит получения ссылок из базы (например 50,000) и при каждом запуске вашего скрипта меняете лимит получения списка ссылок `LIMIT 0,50000  LIMIT 50001,100000` т.д,  и при каждом выполеннии скрипта создаёте новый `xml` файл (sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml, sitemap3.xml).
После того как вы сгенерируете все файлы `xml` вам необходимо будет подготовить их для поисковых роботов.

> Использование файлов индекса Sitemap (для группировки нескольких
>   файлов Sitemap)

Вы может подключить все ваши `xml` файлы в один файл и этот один, главный файл 'скормить' ботов, пример подключения файлов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>20018-04-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>20018-04-03T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```